# Measure how quickly users abandon slowly loading pages

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to measure how quickly users abandon slowly loading pages.

My plan was to register a listener for the ["unload"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload) event as soon as possible, and then send the value of [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) using [`navigator.sendBeacon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)

My problem is that the "unload" event appears to not fire if ["DOMContentLoaded"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) hasn't fired yet.  I suppose that makes sense ... can something be unloaded if it hasn't been loaded yet?  But I still need a workaround to measure how quickly users abandon the page if they abandon before "DomContentLoaded".

I've attempted to listen for the ["abort"](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-abort) event, but it doesn't seem to fire.  My guess is that it only fires if a download was interrupted, and isn't fired when DOM parsing is interrupted.

Any suggestions on how to successfully measure this?

PS: suggestions that don't work in all browsers are also welcome.

EDIT: I've read [jQuery ajaxError() handler fires if user leaves page before page finishes loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906023/jquery-ajaxerror-handler-fires-if-user-leaves-page-before-page-finishes-loadin), and tried to build a solution which registers an "abort" handler on an XMLHttpRequest which the server intentionally answers very slowly.  It does produce an event, which fires in the case of navigation, but it doesn't fire if the tab is closed.  There's no guarantee that it runs, unlike the "unload" event.  A solution that always works would be much better.

Comment: Do you have any control over the users' browsers (e.g. you could mandate a browser extension), or is this a web-facing site?

Comment: It's a web facing site.  In fact, new users who have never visited the site before are the most interesting test cases.

Comment: I would suggest that you not rely on any event (especially DOM event). Just send initial timestamp by a JS code somewhere at the begining of HTML (which, therefore, run before DOM is loaded). Then send current timestamp when DOM is fully loaded. This implies some user identification (e.g. using sessions) on server side.

Comment: @hindmost I'm not sure how that will solve my problem.  The users I'm most interested in measuring abandon the page before it loads.  The load event will never fire.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery ajaxError() handler fires if user leaves page before page finishes loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906023/jquery-ajaxerror-handler-fires-if-user-leaves-page-before-page-finishes-loadin)

Comment: _The users I'm most interested in measuring abandon the page before it loads._ This method exactlly allows to track such situations. For each such user you will have logged initial timestamp, but **unlogged** pageload timestamp.

Comment: @hindmost thanks for the suggestion.  I do log the page hits on the server, plus a timestamp from the load event.  So I know how many users abandoned the page.  What I don't know is how long they waited before abandoning the page.

Comment: @Ionut with your duplicate suggestion: are you suggesting I initiate an AJAX request which is designed to finish slowly, with the intention of listening for an error event if the user leaves the page?  Will this really work?

Comment: _What I don't know is how long they waited before abandoning the page._ Imho that's fundamentally unreachable info.